# Redirect http GET request on first application run/startup (for initialization)

Tags: c#, .net, web, owin, nancy

I'd like to redirect a request to another module if the application is being run for the first time (nancy).

```
// bootstrapper -> RequestStartup
pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(context =>
    if(!_configuration.FirstRun)
        return null;

    return context.Request.Path != "/app/firstrun" ?
        context.GetRedirect("/app/firstrun") : null;
});
```

The pipeline get's intercepted and the redirection happens - however I somehow loose all information about the request and thus, the `AppModule` never get's called. It also tries to locate a view called "DefaultStatusCodeHandlerResult" somehow (?) which obviously doesn't exist.

```
// app module
public class AppModule : NancyModule {
    public AppModule(ServerConfiguration configuration) {
        Get["firstrun"] = _ => {
            if(!configuration.FirstRun)
                return Response.AsRedirect("/home/");
            return View["FirstRun"];  
        };
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better place to configure this behavior instead of the *before request* pipeline?

Comment: Are you trying to get the same behavior as a WebForms, MVC, IIS, ISAPI,  application startup event  Application_Start()  like defined in globabl.asax for one of these types of projects ?

Comment: @SqlSurfer Nah, I need to set up the application using a custom wizard so I want to throw a FIrstRun page at the user when he visits the web interface for the first time

Comment: I have had the luxury of accomplishing that type of app behavior though identity management or the authentication layer.   A Profile Property such as FirstLogin or similar behavior.  For true public sites cookies not being set has been useful in the past.

Comment: @SqlSurfer Oh, you got that wrong. It's to set up the complete application, not a users account. The first run wizard is aimed at system administrators installing the product.

Comment: Something to determine if it is a first Run? Like OnModel Creation?

Comment: @Aizen See second code line, first excerpt. It's a configuration flag.